# Click on new button redirect to vf page based on the profile

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I have a requirement in which if i click on new button of a custom object, it should get redirected to a VF page if this is a support profile. else it should show the standard page. can someone help me with this. 
Below is the code i have tried.

```
    <apex:page standardController="customobject__c" extensions="customvfpagecontroller1" action="{!redirect}">

    public PageReference redirect() {

    PageReference newPage;
    Id tProfile = [select Id from Profile where Name = 'TSupport' limit 1][0].Id;
    Id profileId=userinfo.getProfileId();
    if(profileId == tProfile)
    { 
        newPage = Page.vfpage1;
        return newPage.setRedirect(true);
    } else {
        //it should redirect to standard new page of the custom object

    }
```

Comment: Did you already try to do anything?

Comment: I tried the below code but it doesnt seems to be working. and I have added reDirect to the page action. public PageReference redirect() {

        PageReference newPage;
  Id tProfile = [select Id from Profile where Name = 'TSupport' limit 1][0].Id;
  Id profileId=userinfo.getProfileId();
        if(profileId == tProfile)
        { 
   newPage = Page.custompage1;
            return newPage.setRedirect(true);
        } else {
  //This should redirect to standard new page of the customobecject 
            return null
        }

Comment: it will be better to add your code  to body of question. People will be able to quickly understand how to help you

Answer (score 0):

On the Custom Object page, at the very top click "Buttons, Links, and Actions" > New Button or Link.

Label it New, and Name it New_Custom or something.

Then your logic can be along the lines of

```
IF({!$Profile.Name}=='TSupport','/apex/vfpage1',URLFOR($Action.CustomObject__c.New, null, save=1))
```

You'll unfortunately have to statically set the /apex/vfpage1 since $Page is not supported there.